# How can I improve the appearance of an old concrete storage room floor?

Tags: flooring

[image]

What I'd like to know is the best and least expensive way to dress up an old concrete storage floor ? I thought about paint or stain or a mixture of both.   Do u have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SE. When you combine "best" and "least expensive" you are asking a question that's largely subjective, and therefore off-topic. Please edit to ask something more specific.

Comment: I think your concrete looks great already

Answer (score 1):

Linoleum square tiles are cheap, ~0.88/ea and can be cut/scored with a utility knife and then snapped but the floor needs to be sound and flat. All high spots removed. Do a search for installing linoleum square tiles.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options.  Asking for "the best" depends on your values—not anybody else—so I list options and you choose.

- Skim coat with more concrete.  This makes the appearance uniform and smooths over deviations.  However, this introduces a "step up" edge which may be undesirable.
- Sanding/grinding the surface.  This is the most messy, noisy, and likely the most perilous.  What if there is some subsurface reinforcing bar (re bar)?  What if the concrete is thin in some spots?
- Flooring:  tile, linoleum, wood laminate, carpet, hardwood, etc.

If you are okay with a painting solution, maybe also reduce the amount of light in the room.  :-)